# Rmagic memory use while resizing images

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, rmagick

When resizing images memory usage increases by 40 MB to 80ish MB. These are on files that vary in size but none of them are bigger then 300 kb.

After a bit of profiling I found the offending method.

```
def avatar_resize path
  img = Magick::Image.read(path).first
  img.resize_to_fit(200,200).to_blob
end
```

Is this big increase in memory usage normal or do I need to do something else to eliminate these huge spikes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to create or composite images? If not you could use using mini magick instead. Rmagick shares memory with rails while mini magick has a separate memory allocation for mogrify.

Comment: I will eventually need support for other transformations and special effects, but for what I am doing right now, this might be a good solution. Thank you

Comment: It seemed to work well on my desktop but I pushed it to my server which is running in Passenger, and I still get the same behavior as I saw with RMagick. mogrify is taking as much memory as before. Could it be the call to_blob that the other poster suggested?

Comment: It could be to_blob that is causing the spike. I'm guessing the goal to save the file in the database? Are you using a file helper lib like carrierwave or paperclip? Maybe try this tutorial out and see if you get the same spike http://patshaughnessy.net/2009/5/29/paperclip-sample-app-part-3-saving-file-attachments-in-a-database-blob-column

Comment: I tried Paperclip but ran into so many issues it was much easier to roll my own. I will look into carrierwave. I am storing images in the database to get around storing them in public/, but I think I will try to find a better solution and still be able to restrict who can see images. So far the only other solution I have found is to rename the image files into a long hash or other gibberish, but that seems kludgy and smacks of privacy through obscurity.

Comment: Carrierwave has a Mongoid module for saving images files in Mongo (a document database). You also have the option of saving files in various cloud stores like Amazon's S3, of course this is still not as private as in the DB.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably try and avoid using .to_blob and write the image to file as that is storing your image in memory as is most likely contributing to your high memory usage.